# What information does an OpenVPN provider store about me

Tags: openvpn

I was wondering what information is stored about me when I connect to an OpenVPN VPN provider. For example, can the provider know my operating system? I cannot seem to find any docs about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a provider can do in theory, is doing in practice and publicly admitting/promising  to do or not do are three different things.

A provider **must store**

- your account details, otherwise you can't log in.

They will have always have access to (but not necessarily storing that information) :

- the public IP-address you connect from
- all (encrypted) traffic that is transmitted over your VPN connection
- according to [the OpenVPN manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/) the software itself will send at least the following information (but more when configured to do so with `–push-peer-info`) :

  - `IV_VER=<version>` — the client OpenVPN version
  - `IV_PLAT=[linux|solaris|openbsd|mac|netbsd|freebsd|win]` — the client OS platform
  - `IV_LZO_STUB=1` — if client was built with LZO stub capability
  - `IV_LZ4=1` — if the client supports LZ4 compressions.
  - `IV_PROTO=2` — if the client supports peer-id floating mechansim
  - `IV_NCP=2` — negotiable ciphers, client supports –cipher pushed by the server, a value of 2 or greater indicates client supports AES-GCM-128 and AES-GCM-256.
  - `IV_UI_VER=<gui_id> <version>` — the UI version of a UI if one is running, for example “de.blinkt.openvpn 0.5.47” for the Android app.